# Hibernate getting data from query with case

Tags: java, database, hibernate, plsql

I'm fetching data from DB with following query:

```
with t1(x) as(
select level - 1
from dual
connect by level <= 4

select *  -- actual query
from t1
order by case x
         when 0 then 'expire'
         when 1 then 'approval'
         when 2 then 'pending'
         when 3 then 'counting'
         end
```

I need to perform this query by using Hibernate.

1) Could you tell me if it's possible to get query with following criteria?

```
criteria.createAlias(sortField, 
sortField + ", CURRENT_DATE " + newNameFromCase);
```

If not, what do I have to do to get `Result` from my query?

I have looked for Hibernate annotations but did not find anything.

I must add that my project is not using XML configuration file for hibernate.

Comment: This query can't be translated to HQL or criteria. Use SQL.

Comment: Thank you for answer mate. What about Projections.property (something, "my sql querry" ) ? The same situation?

Comment: Such a method doesn't even exist. Read the javadoc.